# Opening Pdf file url in browser which retrieved from Azure blob storage with sas token embedded

Tags: reactjs, azure-blob-storage

Hi I'm using React on Frontend, I need to display the pdf file on browser by getting the URL comes from BE which is a URL of eg: `https://${storageAccountName}.blob.core.windows.net/${containerName}/${file}?${sasToken}`. I've used `href` to open the pdf in new tab by clicking on that pdf say container.
But on opening It displaying in the binary string format

```
%PDF-1.3
1 0 obj
<</Type /XObject /Subtype /Image /Name /Im1 /Width 1700 /Height 2200 /Length 270870 /ColorSpace /DeviceGray /BitsPerComponent 8 /Filter [ /DCTDecode ] >> stream
�����JFIF����������C�

(1#%(:3=<9387@H\N@DWE78PmQW_bghg>Mqypdx\egc���������������������    
���}�!1AQa"q2���#B��R��$3br�    
%&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz������������������������������������������������������������������������������������?���m�������y����w���pQ��kO�-�PE��R�1GzR)(��))�Q�\њ3Fi(�-�QI�Bh���Fih�4f��f�4f�њLњ3Fi3Fh��
N���Fh���3Fi    ���4��4f�њ3Fh�&h���њLњ3FisIKIJ
```

How I need to approach on React in Frontend or anything need to be done from BE or Azure storage account.

Thanks in advance..

The pdf file need to be open in a new tab is expected

Comment: Please check the content type property of the blob. More than likely it is set incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

**I tried in my environment and got the below results:**

> `https://${storageAccountName}.blob.core.windows.net/${containerName}/${file}?${sasToken}`. I've used `href` to open the pdf in a new tab by clicking on that pdf say container.   But on opening It displays in the binary string format.

To display the PDF file in the browser, you can use the  **`<embed>`**  tag in your React component and also **`content-type: "application/pdf"`** Here's an example:

**pdfviewer.js**

```js
import React from 'react';

function PdfViewer(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <embed src={props.pdfUrl} type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="600px" />
    </div>
  );
}

export default PdfViewer;
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import PdfViewer from './Pdfviewer';

function App() {
  function openPdfInNewTab(pdfUrl) {
    const newWindow = window.open();
    newWindow.document.body.innerHTML = `<html><body><div id="pdf-viewer"></div></body></html>`;
    ReactDOM.render(<PdfViewer pdfUrl={pdfUrl} />, newWindow.document.getElementById('pdf-viewer'));
  }

  return (
    <div>
       <button onClick={() => openPdfInNewTab('https://${storageAccountName}.blob.core.windows.net/${containerName}/${file}?${sasToken}')}>Open PDF in new tab</button>
</div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Output:**
[image]

When I open the **`http://localhost:3000`** in the browser it opens the pdf file.

**Browser:**
[image]

[image]